# how to initialize an array to a given size in haxe

Tags: arrays, haxe

I was wondering if there is a way to initialize an array to a given size `n` (,like in c++'s `std::vector` constructor, or @steve richey's answer below without the hint element hack)?

My thought was to push back `n` default elements into the newly created array, but even this seems not possible because there seems to be no way to define a default element, as shown in the original question below:

-- original question --

I am trying to write a static function in haxe (as of 3.0.1) to create an array of a given size n containing types of an arbitrary type T. I couldn't figure out how to use Type.createEmptyInstance() correctly for this. The closest I can get is:

```
class Main {
    static public function new_array<T>(n:Int):Array<T> {
    var a:Array<T> = new Array<T>();
    var t:T = new T(); //not OK
    for (i in 0...n)
        a.push(Type.createEmptyInstance(Type.getClass(t)));
    return a;
}
    static public function main() {
            var a:Array<Int> = new_array(3);
    }
}
```

The second line in new_array() is problematic. Compiler says: `Main.hx:4: characters 12-19 : Only generic type parameters can be constructed`.

My question is, how to make such a function work for an array of any type T.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

In Haxe, Arrays are not a fixed length.  You can use Vectors instead, which behave similarly but have a fixed length.

```
class Test {
    static function main(){
        var vector = new haxe.ds.Vector(5); // Starting Length
        vector[0] = "zero";
        vector[3] = "three";
        // vector[7] = "seven"; // Will cause Runtime error on some platforms! 
        for ( val in vector ) {
            trace( val );
            // "zero"
            // null
            // null
            // "three"
            // null
        }
    }
}
```

Please note, vectors are "Abstracts", so they wrap an underlying type.  On some platforms (eg Flash) that's a real Vector, and it will throw errors for outside of bounds access.  On other platforms (eg JS) the underlying implementation is an Array, so it may not throw an error for fetching an item outside the bounds, etc.  If you stick to non-broken sensible usage you should be fine though :)

As a side note about Arrays, if you do something like:

```
var arr = [];
arr[0] = "zero";
arr[8] = "eight";
```

Some platforms will pad items 1-7 with "null", and some will not - the behaviour depends on the platform and is not reliable.

See:

- [Array API](http://api.haxe.org/Array.html)
- [Vector API](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/ds/Vector.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But I need to get this work for Array<T>, because I need to add elements to the container. Also, what I needed for Array<T> as described above is more like the C++ vector<>.resize() function, which can be used to initialize or reallocate storage for an C++ "array".

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this:

```
@:generic static public function new_Array<T>( ArrayType:T, Length:Int ):Array<T> {
    var empty:Null<T> = null;
    var newArray:Array<T> = new Array<T>();

    for ( i in 0...Length ) {
        newArray.push( empty );
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

Then, when you want to create a new Array:

`var myArray:Array<Int> = new_Array( 1, 25 );`

Admittedly, using 1 to signal that the type should be `Int` is a bit of a hack, and someone else might know a better way, but hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

here's a simple way if you need to set the length of the array even if it doesn't have any data in it:

```
    var myArray:Array<String> = new Array<String>();   //in this case array of strings
    myArray[5] = null;                                 //in this case setting length to 6
```

elements 0 - 4 are not being set (if you debug they are not listed) but they will be treated as null.